# Confusing implementation of F# CodeDom

Tags: f#, codedom

I'm trying to create a class and a method in it. For C# and VB, the CodeDom providers emit preditable output, but the F# CodeDom provider emits the following. I'm wondering why.

```
exception ReturnException8abef2fbb2404165b4b8690157bd3a49 of obj
exception ReturnNoneException8abef2fbb2404165b4b8690157bd3a49

type
    // Hello

    test = class
        new() as this =
            {
            }
        abstract my_method : unit -> unit
        default this.my_method  () =
            ()
    end
```

Ignoring the exception stuff (I guess the provider is still a bit buggy), I'm curious as to why I get such a weird definition with `new() as this`, an abstract method and a default implementation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Not my fault that many questions I ask don't get useful answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code generated by the CodeDOM generator is weird, but it is mostly valid F# code that compiles. As kvb points out, the definition of constructor is valid. It would be nicer if the CodeDOM provider generated code using implicit syntax, but that wouldn't work well if you had multiple constructors.

As for the exceptions, these are used to emulate imperative `return` construct (as in C#). For example, you cannot directly write the following in F#:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  if (i == 5) return;
```

So the CodeDOM generator uses exception to emulate `return` and `try .. with` to handle it.

The usual coding style in F# is simply a bit different from C#/VB and the CodeDOM data structures were designed mainly for C#/VB. If you want to generate nice F# code, then writing your own code generator may be a better idea. Alternatively, someone could create F# CodeDOM provider that wouldn't support all features, but would generate nice code.

Comment: I remember an interview with someone from Microsoft's language team (I forgot who). When he was asked about CodeDOM, he said something like "CodeDOM can represent *any* programming language, as long as that programming language is C#. Or VB.NET obviously, but they are the same language anyway." Going via Expression Trees, F# quotations or a custom AST and writing a custom code generator is probably the way to go.

Comment: But regarding the abstract method - do we really need it? I mean, to have a method can't I just have `member this.MyMethod =` or something to that effect?

Comment: @Dmitri: I'm not sure if I remember how abstract methods work exactly in CodeDOM. Anyway, if it is supposed to compile, then the method must be abstract (with default implementation) because your tree may include another class that overrides it (which wouldn't work with just `member x.MyMethod ..`) - and it would work this way in C#. I'm not sure if there is a way to specify that method is non-virtual in CodeDOM.

Comment: @Jörg: Expression trees are incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

This looks fine to me.

```
new() as this = {}
```

is just an empty default constructor, and the abstract method with default implementation is how you define a virtual method in F# (see [section 8.14.2 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597572)).